# EJS template select option showing selected="" instead of just selected (bug in ejs?)

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

when I render this EJS template

```
<select>
   <option value="10" <%= results.coordinates.x==="10" ? "selected" : "" %> >10</option>
</select>
```

It results in this:

```
<select>
   <option value="10" selected="">10</option>
</select>
```

The expected result should be this:

```
<select>
   <option value="10" selected>10</option>
</select>
```

Why is it showing up as `selected=""`? is this an ejs bug or a bug in my code? MDN says is should be just `selected`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: View the response directly and not with the browsers DOM Inspector.

Comment: one thing to note is that for me it didn't take effect on a page refresh, but only after going back a page and re-opening the page. Perhaps it has something to do with my node/nodemon app. but someone might vind this helpfull during debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with some DOM inspectors failing to display minimized attributes as minimized. As long as the rendered source actually uses the minimized syntax, don't worry, it'll work correctly.

(But even if the rendered source is showing up as `selected=""`, [you won't be penalized by the validator](https://checker.html5.org/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%21DOCTYPE+html%3E%3Chtml+lang%3Den%3E%3Ctitle%3EBoolean+attribute+with+empty+value%3C%2Ftitle%3E%250A%3Cselect%3E%3Coption+selected%3D%22%22%3EItem%3C%2Foption%3E%3C%2Fselect%3E), and the mere presence of the attribute will always be treated correctly by the browser.)

Comment: Oh wow didn't know that, you are right, it's correct in the actual source. Thank you I'll mark this as solved